# Cannot find module al hacer ng new h

Tags: nodejs, angular, npm

Instalé nodejs usando chocolatey;

```
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

luego npm, ya no recuerdo el comando exacto, creo que era:
npm install -g

Hasta ahí, todo bien. Pero si intentaba crear un proyecto de angular, ng new h
me decía: cannot find module.

NODE_PATH

```
C:\Users\Jhon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin
```

La ruta donde busca y el node_path eran distintos.

En la ruta donde ví que él buscaba pegué los archivos de nodejs, es decir la carpeta modules, lo otro ya estaba.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora parece que intenta funcionar, saca este error cuando trata de crear el proyecto angular

La primera parte

```
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Jhon\AngularT1\t\
node_modules\.staging\core-js-801a72c4\library\fn\array\virtual\keys.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Jhon\AngularT1\t\
node_modules\.staging\core-js-801a72c4\library\fn\array\virtual\last-index-of.js
'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Jhon\AngularT1\t\
node_modules\.staging\core-js-801a72c4\library\fn\array\virtual\map.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Jhon\AngularT1\t\
node_modules\.staging\core-js-801a72c4\library\fn\array\virtual\reduce-right.js'
```

y sigue así, luego

```
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Jhon\AngularT1\t\
node_modules\.staging\core-js-4f69d60f\features\data-view\index.js'
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Jhon\AngularT1\t\node_modules\.staging\typescript-424d3ee
d\lib\tr\diagnosticMessages.generated.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Jhon\AngularT1\
t\node_modules\.staging\typescript-424d3eed\lib\tr\diagnosticMessages.generated.
json'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Jh
on\AngularT1\t\node_modules\.staging\typescript-424d3eed\lib\tr\diagnosticMessag
es.generated.json'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Jhon\
AngularT1\t\node_modules\.staging\typescript-424d3eed\lib\tr\diagnosticMessages.
generated.json'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\Jhon\\AngularT1\\t\\node_modules\\.staging\\types
cript-424d3eed\\lib\\tr\\diagnosticMessages.generated.json'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\\Users\\Jho
n\\AngularT1\\t\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-424d3eed\\lib\\tr\\diagnosti
cMessages.generated.json'",
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Jhon\\AngularT1\\t\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescr
ipt-424d3eed\\lib\\tr\\diagnosticMessages.generated.json',
npm ERR!   parent: 't'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or ant
ivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check t
he
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended
).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jhon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-02T12_39_29_4
24Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.

C:\Users\Jhon\AngularT1>
```

Comment: Por favor, transcribe (copia y pega) los mensajes de error como texto para que puedan ayudar a otras personas que busquen el problema en buscadores. Gracias.

Comment: Para copiar y pegar desde el símbolo de sistema simplemente selecciona con el cursor (o pulsa el botón derecho y elige "Marcar") y tras seleccionar el texto (en forma de recuadro) pulsa ENTER para que se introduzca en el portapapeles. En las capturas no se ve la instrucción que estás ejecutando, ni la ruta en la que estás, ni la parte superior de los mensajes (el primer error), etc. También sería bueno saber cómo instalaste (qué pasos seguiste) `nodejs`, `npm` y `@angular/cli`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de mucho buscar (y angustia) pude resolverlo, como moví las variables del sistema cuando estaba trabajando con Java, Eclipse y Selenium al hacer testing, move la variable path, la variable del sistema, abajo, la cambié así

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;%SystemRoot%\System32
```

Le agregué la última parte y ahora funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Puede que no tengas instalada la librería correspondiente al Angular CLI, prueba lo siguiente y después vuelve a ejecutar el *ng new*.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: Justo iba a decirlo como comentario x) Mi +1

Comment: Lo hice, instaló, sin embargo sigue el error @DarwinGonzalez

Comment: Pero ¿es el mismo error o es otro diferente? ¿Podrías actualizar la pregunta incluyendo un "copia/pega" del mensaje de error? Por favor, usa capturas de pantalla sólo para mostrar cosas que no se puedan describir en texto.

Comment: Pregunta actualizada @DarwinGonzalez